# Naming fields in NumPy Arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am interested in creating a 2d numpy array where each row can be referred to by a unique field name. I have experimented with record arrays like such:

```
>>> a = np.recarray((2, 10), dtype=[('x', 'f8'), ('y', 'f8')])
```

But this fails when I do simple arithmetic like so:

```
>>> a += 4.0
TypeError: invalid type promotion
```

Is there a way to use named fields that doesn't require setting different data types for each field, or that won't fail when I try to do array math?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`recarray` and `structured` arrays are not designed to be convenient ways of naming columns.  They are meant to hold a mix of data types, the kind of thing you might load from a CSV file - strings, integers, floats, dates.

The operations that can be performed across fields are limited.  As you found, you cannot add a value to the whole array.  You have to add it field by field - provided the field type is right.  Similarly you can't sum the 2 fields, or take their mean (with `np.sum` or `np.mean` functions).  Also can't reshape or transpose those arrays (exchanging fields for rows, etc).

[Constructing np.array with overlapping fields in dtype](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36432067/constructing-np-array-with-overlapping-fields-in-dtype) is a current SO question that illustrates several ways of accessing a couple of fields as a 2 column array.

It is better to stick with normal nd arrays unless you really need the added flexibility of a structured array.  If you want to access columns by name, consider defining variables, e.g. `ind_x=0`, `ind_y=1`, so you can use `a[2:5, ind_x]`.

Answer (score 2):

recarray allows access to fields like an object attribute. So this works.

```
a.x += 4
a.y += 5
```

Answer (score 2):

`np.recarray((2, 10), dtype=[('x', 'f8'), ('y', 'f8')])` returns a matrix of size `2x10` where each element is a tuple of two elements. Thus, the operation `a+4.0` has no meaning at all.

You have to access each field of a recarray independently:

```
a[0,0].x += 4.0
```

Comment: `a[0,0].x` is the preferred way of indexing a 2d array (rec or not).